# Why port forwarding not working in my WiMax router even though I forwarded it?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, webserver

I am using BSNL WIMax Modem. I forwarded my port 6999 to 7010 to IP address 192.168.1.243.

Using 192.168.1.234:7001 , I able to access my web server. But when I input my extrnal_ip_address:7001 , the browser displays unable to connect.

I check the port 7001 in some port checking site . They shows that 7001 in opened and I also able to Ping.

Why this happening ?

I also disabled firewall in my PC and unchecked the "Enable Firewall" option ion WiMAx modem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because your router doesn't support NAT lookup. You won't be able to access internal computers using your external IP while in the LAN, but the external IP will work to the rest of the world.

If you want to test a website through external IP, then you can use a proxy. I like [Anonymouse](http://anonymouse.org/), but you can choose from thousands of them at [proxy.org](http://proxy.org/).

See [Is NAT Loopback on my router a security problem?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem) for some debate on whether NAT lookup is safe or not.

Comment: Your are correct, I suppose. absence of "NAT Lookup" will producing inconvenience in development systems.

Comment: My problem resolved. I tested from other computer and site loads :-) @gronostaj